# css horizontal submenu not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a  css horizontal menu. the problem is that my submenu won't float..

What have i done  wrong?

My HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">

    <li class="button"><a href="#"><span>Je Studie</span></a> 
        <ul>

            <li><a href='#'>Programma</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Begeleiding</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Locaties</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Open dag</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Toelatingseisen</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Kosten</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Aanmelden</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Nieuws</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="button"><a href = '#'><span>Voor ouders</span></a></li>

    <li class="button"><a href = '#'><span>Voor decanen</span></a></li>

    <li class="button"><a href = '#'><span>Voor bedrijven</span></a></li>

    <li class="button"><a href = '#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And my CSS is like:

```
.nav{position:relative;}
.nav a{display:block; color:black;}


.nav li{
    float:left;
    margin:0;

    position:relative;

}
.nav ul{visibility:hidden; position:absolute; top:100%; left:0;}
.nav li:hover>ul{visibility:visible; }
```

thanks!

Comment: Just as a recommendation, I would use `display:none;` and `display:block;` instead of `visibility`, but it seems to work for me fine. I guess I don't understand the issue.

Comment: Yeah it looks fine here, maybe explaining what you mean by "won't float" and maybe what browser/s you are finding the issues in, it would help narrow down the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working example

**html**

```
<ul class="nav">

    <li class="button"><a href="#"><span>Je Studie</span></a> 
        <ul>

            <li><a href='#'>Programma</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Begeleiding</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Locaties</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Open dag</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Toelatingseisen</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Kosten</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Aanmelden</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Nieuws</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="button"><a href = '#'><span>Voor ouders</span></a></li>

    <li class="button"><a href = '#'><span>Voor decanen</span></a></li>

    <li class="button"><a href = '#'><span>Voor bedrijven</span></a></li>

    <li class="button"><a href = '#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**Css**

```
.nav a{display:block; color:black;}
.nav li{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
    margin-right: 20px;

}
.nav ul{ position:absolute; top:100%; left:0;width: 300px;display: none;}
.nav ul li{float: left;width: 100px;}
.nav li:hover>ul{ display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<nav id="navbar">
     <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Programma</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Begeleiding</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Locaties</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Open dag</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Toelatingseisen</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Kosten</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Aanmelden</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Nieuws</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</nav>`

Comment: CSS #navbar li{display:inline-block;}

Comment: sorry, I don't know the correct way to post answers on this site :-P